# How to show all the queryset result in one cell of table with Django

Tags: django

I want to show all the queryset result in one cell of table. Right now,rows in ECMs shows queryset directly as shown in below image. But I want to show each items in queryset in one cell. Could anyone give me any advice how to implement?
[image]

**html file**

```
% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
{% load staticfiles %}

<h2>Results comparison </h2>

<div class="row">
    <h4>annual energy consumption</h4>
    <svg width="1200" height="400"></svg>
</div>

<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Version</th>
            <th>Diff</th>
            <th>ECMs</th>
            <th>Area[m2]</th>
            <th>EUI[kWh/m2]</th>
            <th>Unmet hour[h]</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    {% for project in object_list %}
        <tr>
            <td><a href="{% url 'project:detail' project.pk %}">{{project.version}}</a></td>
            <td>{{project.diff}}</td>
            <td>{{project.ecms.all}}</td>
            <td>{{project.area.total_area|floatformat:"0"}}</td>
            <td>{{project.energy.euipertotal|floatformat:"0"}}</td>
            <td>{{project.unmet.heating|add:project.unmet.cooling}}</td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have multiple objects within the queryset, you will need to find a way to show all the ecms in one cell. For example:

```
<td>{% for ecm in project.ecms.all %} {{ ecm }} {% endfor %}</td>
```

This will call `str(ecm)` for all objects in the queryset. May not be easy to visualize.

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution I have,
On your ECMs Model,

```
def __str__(self):  # __unicode__(self) in python2
    return __all__  # OR format as you like.
```

If it can't help let us know and explain more.